# What is wrong with the Search Form codes?

Tags: runtime-error, ms-access-2013, search-form

I have a Search Form which have a sub form in it.

I keep getting Run-time error '3075': Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression '[MC_No] like '*' [Customer] like '*' [Date_Recorded] = #23/11/2016# AND [Product] like '*".

Can anybody identify my error? I have checked every single line. Maybe I missed out on something.

These are my codes

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

Dim strDatePicker As String
Dim cboMC As String
Dim strProduct As String
Dim cboCustomer As String
Dim sql As String

sql = "select * FROM 3_OEE WHERE "

If IsDate(Me.DatePicker) Then
strDatePicker = " [Date_Recorded] = #" & DateValue(Me.DatePicker) & "#"
Else
strDatePicker = " [Date_Recorded] like '*'"
End If

If IsNull(Me.MC_No) Then
cboMC = " [MC_No] like '*'"
Else
cboMC = " [MC_No] like '" & Me.MC_No & "'"

If IsNull(Me.Customer) Then
cboCustomer = " [Customer] like '*'"
Else
cboCustomer = " [Customer] = '" & Me.Customer & "'"
End If

Me.subfrmOEE.Form.RecordSource = sql (*Error highlights this code*)
Me.subfrmOEE.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Did you have something missing? From your error message, it missing `AND` or `OR` in your sql.  From your code, you haven't concat other `where clause`, which leave `select * from 3_OEE where` for the `RecordSource` only

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything is in. @Alex Does it have to do with my subform

Comment: @Andy is right, your additional where conditions are never getting added to `sql`. The other problem you look to be having is that `MC_No` and `Customer` are returning empty strings rather than Null. The code you have posted can't possibly be generating the error message you're seeing. Is there anything else that is trying to set the record source on the sub form? Can you step through the code to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing? Manually check the value of `sql` at various points along the way.

Answer (score 0):

On the line with the error, your variable `sql` is the same as it was when you first declared it, i.e.: `"select * FROM 3_OEE WHERE "`.

This is not a valid query. You need to either remove `WHERE` from the end of that query or append to the `sql` variable the rest of the query statement (in other words, add the `WHERE` conditions to the end of the query).